# How to optimize treeAggregate of LBFGS on spark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, data-mining, apache-spark-mllib, bigdata

I'm run LBFGS on spark, with 5 features and 10w records, and found treeAggregate this:

[image]

We can see the treeAggregte is time-consuming

I have 100 cores, and every job 'treeAggregate at LBFGS.scala:218' has 1w+ tasks

Comment: i have ran 'coalesce' on my trainData, reduce partitions equal to cores, and got a big improvement. But why?